# Derivative of rigid transformation using exponential map

Tags: lie-algebras, lie-derivative, rigid-transformation

I have been looking into Lie algebra in order to compute an optimization to figure out the rigid transformation of a set of points.

For now, I have calculated the transformation given an axis-angle representation of a rotation $w$ and a translation $t$:

$T = \begin{bmatrix} 
    R & t \\
    0 & 1
  \end{bmatrix}
= 
\begin{bmatrix} 
    e^{[w]_+} & t \\
    0 & 1
  \end{bmatrix}
$

where $e^{[w]_+} = I + \frac{sin\theta}{\theta}[w]_+ + \frac{1 - cos\theta}{\theta^2}[w]_+^2$

and $[w]_+ = \begin{bmatrix} 
    0 & w_z & -w_y \\
    -w_z & 0 & w_x \\
    w_y & -w_x & 0
  \end{bmatrix} = $

$= w_x \begin{bmatrix} 
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & -1 & 0
  \end{bmatrix} + w_y \begin{bmatrix} 
    0 & 0 & -1 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 0
  \end{bmatrix} + w_z \begin{bmatrix} 
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    -1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0
  \end{bmatrix}$

This seems to be the correct transformation, since I get the same transformation as with traditional methods.

However, now I am trying to calculate the derivative of this transformation with respect to each $w_i$. In my calculations, I get that the derivative of the transformation with respect to $w_x$ is:

$\frac{\partial T}{\partial w_x} = \begin{bmatrix} 
    \frac{\partial R}{\partial w_x} & 0 \\
    0 & 0
  \end{bmatrix}$

$\frac{\partial R}{\partial w_x} = \frac{\partial e^{[w]_+}}{\partial w_x} = e^{[w]_+} \frac{\partial [w]_+}{\partial w_x} = R \begin{bmatrix} 
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & -1 & 0
  \end{bmatrix}$

However this doesn't seem to be correct, since I'm doing a numerical check and it comes out different. Any clue on what I am doing wrong?

Note: my numercial check is

$\frac{\partial R}{\partial w_x} = \frac{R(w+[\epsilon, 0, 0]) - R(w)}{\epsilon}$

Comment: Seems like this approach only works for small angles.